# The input line is too long when starting kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run Kafka message queue on Windows.

I'm usin this tutorial - https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os

When i try to run it with comand - .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties

and i get an error:
**The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

kafka location - C:\kafka_2.11-1.0.0

Comment: You can find more details here https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2020/08/30/kafka-2-6-up-and-running-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 123):

This is because of the long length of the path because of the folder name 'kafka_2.11-1.0.0'. Just rename the folder to something small, like just 'kafka'.

Comment: Then restarting CMD and running the command works. In the previous CMD I found %CLASSPATH% included too much paths.

Comment: Worked for me !! Thanks.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: @niaomingjian Thanks. My CMD's classpath is occupied by zookeeper server. Now I'm using PowerShell to start kafka server.

Comment: Renaming to a shorter name works, or rather it happens to work because Windows (better, cmd.exe) has a command line length limit of 8191 characters, as stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation)

Comment: I had to rename the full directory path from C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Desenvolvimento\Servidores\kafka_2.12-2.7.0
to C:\kafka

Comment: Don't forget to rename log.dirs in server.properties ;)

Comment: preferably keep in  the short path, it is little tricky but works, i keep kafka in -> c:\kafaka\<hompath>

Comment: I actually thought of this for a sec but discarded the idea...made the same mistake again. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

**The Problem**

The `kafka-run-class.bat` file performs a bunch of CLASSPATH :concat calls that make the CLASSPATH very long.

Depending on your environment, too long: Windows cmd.exe environment has a limit of 8191 characters.

**Solutions**

Edit `kafka-run-class.bat` so that ...

1. make it so that CLASSPATH is not used or set elsewhere
2. make paths shorter so that concat produces a string smaller than than 8191 characters
3. make concat use the whole folder instead of every single jar (via `libs/*`)

**Example**

Here is an example of an edit to `kafka-run-class.bat` ([source](https://github.com/kafka-dev/kafka/issues/61)) that uses the 2nd approach:

replace ...

```
rem Classpath addition for release
for %%i in ("%BASE_DIR%\libs\*") do (
    call :concat "%%i"
)
```

... by this ...

```
rem Classpath addition for release
call :concat "%BASE_DIR%\libs\*;"
```

Comment: I wish I would understand the solution suggested while I am really grateful for the explanation.

Comment: Wow, I count 14 "concat" calls in kafka-run-class.bat.  Youch.   instances I found :   Line 47: call :concat "%%i"
Line 52: call :concat "%%i"
Line 57: call :concat "%%i"
Line 62: call :concat "%%i"
Line 67: call :concat "%%i"
Line 71: call :concat "%%i"
Line 76: call :concat "%%i"
Line 80: call :concat "%%i"
Line 85: call :concat "%%i"
Line 88: call :concat "%BASE_DIR%\connect\%%p\build\dependant-libs\*"
Line 94: REM call :concat "
Line 96: call :concat "%BASE_D
Line 101: call :concat "%%i"
Line 188: :concat

Comment: @petermeissner Iam facing the same problem. But unfortunately kafka and zookeeper is starting. While trying to start kafka connect this solution fails

Comment: Have you considered submitting the patch to the Kafka maintainers?

Answer (score 19):

Just moving the Kafka path to a much smaller root path solved the issue. For e.g. "C:\Kafka"

Comment: u were right. Thank you Anandji.
I moved to root position of my c drive & now the command got invoked successfully.

--------
before: 
-----------
C:\Users\srikumarki\Documents\Softwares\kafka
-----------
after: 
-----------
C:\kafka
-----------

Answer (score 11):

**Above both options didn't work for me.**

I have just moved an unzipped directory to C:/ drive and started power shell in **Administrator** mode and tried the desired commands, the zookeeper and broker started smoothly.

Answer (score 7):

I have copied everything to C:/tools/kafka and it works fine. The problem was indeed the too long path to kafka.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some explanation and details.

Comment: Just place kafka on your root directory like this C:\kafka and it would work just fine

Answer (score 5):

For me, it worked only after keeping the Kafka folder right under C directory, so the path looked like C:\Kafka. I am sure this will work.

Comment: Worked for me as well after moving the entire Kafka folder to C:\kafka_2.13-3.1.2\bin\windows. Then set env variable.

Answer (score 3):

Windows command-line has issues with long command execution. 
Use Powershell instead.

Comment: Powershell did not solve my issue either. It has the same 8191 character limitation as stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd-exe-command-line-string-limitation) as cmd.exe.

Answer (score 3):

Kafka folder/directory path length needs to be decreased.
Use short folder/directory path then it should start working.

Answer (score 3):

The following steps worked for me.

1. Move the Kafka folder close to the root (like C:\kafka).
2. Remove the unwanted path variables from environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

put all the files in other drive like D: or E: and run the command

Answer (score 2):

1. download  kafka.apache.org site
2. extract it
3. rename extracted folder to kafka
4. move renamed folder to C drive c:\kafka (should be short)
5. specify path in zookeeper.properties  & server.properties (c:\kafka)
6. open cmd and execute below command
   C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties*

Answer (score 1):

Place kafka close to the root of your drive so that the path to it is very short.

When you run those Kafka batch files included in the windows directory, they muck with your environment variables (the classpath one) and can create a very long input line to actually run the command/jar.

Also as some others pointed out, ensure you downloaded the binary (yes even though on the Kafka site it is called the Scala binary and there's no mention of Windows anywhere, which can confuse people), not the source code. Also confusing to the lay-user, the source distribution looks similar to the binary distribution when uncompressed, it has all the batch files for example but they won't run.

Answer (score 1):

### The input line is too long when starting kafka

I tried below command but gives me same error

C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties

This happens because path gets append in classpath when we are continuously executing same command on same cmd.

Close your command prompt and open once again and then start zookeeper server.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows just keep Kafka Folder path short
For eg - D/dev/kafka/bin/windows

Answer (score 1):

Closing Zookeeper and Kafka cmd window and reopening it again worked for me. I tried all options above except powershell.

Comment: That's not really a solution, please can you try to explain why the error occurs and how to solve it, otherwise can you delete your answer please

Answer (score 1):

Please check the directory path of your files, it should not contain any "-" in your directory structure where you have kept Kafka. ***Changing the name of the directory from kafka_2.13-2.7.0 --> Kafka*** worked for me.

Comment: This answer should be considered as a tricky-case solution as well. 
Error already tells us to shorten path, it is obvious even for chair.
This solution is what less of us will ever guess on their own.

Comment: Agreed, it's about invalid characters, not length. Spaces are also invalid (so "Program Files" is a no go).

Answer (score 1):

Just remove version(kafka_2.13-3.3.1) prior kafka in folder name(kafka) and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the kafka folder to some shorter name like kafka2.
Open a new command prompt (DO not use existing/opened command prompt)

Answer (score 0):

I tried extracting the downloaded Kafka zip file contacts

```
C:\Kafka and ran the Kafka-server-start.bat
```

from the command prompt (don't run the command prompt as administrator) and that worked.

Running the command prompt as administrator was causing the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `kafka_2.13-2.5.0` if there's any and keep the folder name as simple as possible like `Kafka`, also make sure there are no spaces in the path.

**A working example**: Folder is located in `C:\kafka`.
**A not working example**: Folder is located in `C:\kafka 2\`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. Debugging the bat-files, you can see, that changing into the directory before calling the command that returns with this error and calling it with relative path does not afect the result!
The problem is the CLASSPATH variable. The easiest way to get this shorter for me was to use the command:

```
subst K: <absolute-long-path-to-kafka-dir-with-version>
```

This way I could change into this virtual drive `cd /d K:` and execute the scripts without problem:

```
K:\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat K:\config\server.properties
```

I wrote a wrapper-script that removes the CLASSPATH variable before executing again, because the values are appended every execution (same cmd.exe).

```
set CLASSPATH=
cd /d K:
K:\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat K:\config\server.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename kafka_2.11-1.0.0 to kafka and keep it in C drive. This worked for me.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to solve this is to create a virtual drive from the kafka folder:

```
subst <drive:> path\to\folder
```

example:

```
subst K: C:\Users\me\software\kafkax.x-x.x
```

You can then go to the K: drive and run zookeeper and kafka without problem.

```
cd K:
.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugged and found the issue. Execute the command

```
echo %CLASSPATH%
```

and you will find the culprit :)

All jar files in the `kafka\lib` directory are set in `CLASSPATH` individually. So the error is thrown as

> Input Line too long

**Fix**: add the `CLASSPATH` variable in the environment variable till the kafka base directory.

Answer (score -1):

Run common  .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.propertie from Powershell window, it works without any issue on Window.

For a similar error, for zookeeper I run the zookeeper zkserver.cmd which i downloaded from https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.2/zookeeperStarted.html

Answer (score -1):

****Simple Solution ****
Move your kafka folder in c drive.
example c:\kafka_2.13-3.6.0
then after execute bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat config\zookeeper.properties command it will work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).